# Show content after youtube subs

Tags: javascript

I would need a springboard to create the script.

I need a solution to lock part of the content on wordpress. To view hidden content, the reader will need to start subscribing to youtube channel.

Is there any way to set the condition which checking that the reader has actually started subscribing youtube channel?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that, by using YouTube API and with a script on backend(on your server side) which is going to perform that check. In your YouTube API, Use the `subscriptions#list` method and pass `mine = true` and your channel ID you want to check in `forChannelId`. If the authenticated user is not subscribed to that channel, it will return an empty list, otherwise you can return a code for unlocking hidden content.

Comment: Exactly what I would need :) but if there is more of this content and the readers return after some time. Is there any possibility that the locked content will automatically be shown to people with an active subscription? Without registering on the site.

Comment: Yes, you could make a separate table row and whitelist those users, so they not get locked. I would also use sessions to track returning users. Another approach using firebase to store al that data.